# Angular: "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value" in img src

Tags: angular, url, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm having trouble with the `DomSanitizer` while trying to show an image in AngularJS.
Don't know if i'm storing the `path` wrongly or not `sanitizing` it correctly!

I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value sanitizeImg(C:/xampp/htdocs/ImagenesCompras/rubros/informatica.jpg)
```

**HTML code:**

```
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 f-category" *ngFor="let rubro of rubros">
              <div class="inner">
                 <a [routerLink]="['/mostrarPropiedad', rubro.id]">
                      <span class="imgBox">
                           <img src="sanitizeImg({{rubro.fotoPath}})" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
                      </span>
                      <h6> {{rubro.titulo}}</h6>
                 </a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Angular component**

```
   constructor(private rubrosService: RubrosServiceService,
   private router: Router,
   private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.rubrosService.GetAllRubros().subscribe(
      rubros => this.rubros = rubros,
       );
   }
   sanitizeImg(url): SafeUrl{
      return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
   }
```